# How to count data in different ranges and group by month in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

assume that there is a table like this:

```
sensor_id    temperature   device      date
x01             18           d1      2018-07-01
x02             23           d1      2018-08-01
x01             21           d2      2018-07-01
x02             30           d2      2018-08-01
x01             28           d3      2018-07-01
x02             14           d3      2018-08-01
x01             11           d4      2018-08-01
x02             10           d4      2018-08-01
```

I need a result table like this:

```
below15        above15_below22         above22        month
   0                  2                   1             7
   3                  0                   2             8
```

actually, It groups data by months and counts which sensors are below 15 degrees, above 15 and below 22 degrees, ...
sorry I am not very familiar with MySQL because of my background education.
I write this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as below15,MONTH(date) as month_num FROM `sensor_table` WHERE temperature<15 GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

my problem is how can I generate the rest of the table.

Comment: What about when it's exactly 15?

Comment: @Strawberry  now that I got the answer I use '=' for below 15 and 15 must be in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `case when`  and aggregate funtion `sum`

```
    select sum( case when temperature<15 then 1 else 0 end ) as 
    below15,
    sum(case when temperature>15 and temperature<22 then 1 else 0 end) as 
    above15_below22,
    sum(case when temperature>22 then 1 else 0 end) as above22 ,month(date) 
    as  month from your_table    
    group by  month
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4009a/3

Comment: What about when it's 15?

Comment: @Strawberry have you find anything for 15 in question?